# Unity 2020 project building asm.js files instead of wasm

Tags: unity-game-engine, webassembly, asm.js

I upgraded a project from unity 2018 to unity 2020. the webGL build for unity 2020 should default to wasm (Web assembly) but instead it is building the project with asm.js. I can't figure out how to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

All I needed to do was edit ProjectSettings/projectsettings.asset and set   webGLLinkerTarget: 1

Comment: i cant's find ProjectSettings/projectsettings.asset and set webGLLinkerTarget: 1

Answer (score 1):

You find it in your explorer: Go to your project location, there should be a folder named "ProjectSettings", in there you find the "ProjectSettings.asset".  In the file you can now edit parameters by simply writing and saving.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).